# Why is the FascistLogging ssh logging mode named that?

Tags: ssh, logging, history

The docs describe [Fascist Logging mode](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch05_08.htm) quite well, so I understand what it does.

Basically it is a variant of debug logging enabled with

```
FascistLogging yes
```

But *why* is it named that? I'm sure the original authors had a funny reason behind the name, but I can't think of any analogy to relate logging and fascism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fascism - a tendency toward or actual exercise of strong autocratic or dictatorial control" [Dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fascism)

Fascism is often linked to extremism, control, manipulation and paranoia - so a logging level that is extreme could be described by some as being rather fascist - so that.

Comment: Comment from the sources: "Specifies whether to use verbose logging.  Verbose logging violates the privacy of users and is not recommended."
https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/5ce662a9202240a2f5fa6a9334d58186bdaba50c#diff-74a285b88709826bc2d98c64cc2814798e52b013c7bf1a4c038027f16ead4a3bL234

Comment: Ah that makes sense to me. It's easy for me to forget that these old fundamental libraries originated in a different era when it was common for many users to log in to a shared resource and they had a reasonable expectation of privacy.

Unlike today where I only ssh into machines that only I can see the logs or machines my employer controls and I expect everything is logged.